# How to send a POST request through Swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, postman

I have my controller like this -

```
def create
   if (@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])) && @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: @user.as_json(only: [:email,:authentication_token]),status: :created
   else 
      render json:('Unauthorized Access')
   end  
end
```

When I use Postman to make this request, I choose Body, and form data and adds in the email and password. And this WORKS

[image]

How to use swift to do the same? This is what I have tried

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user_serialized/")

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

let bodyData = "email=Test@test.com&password=Test1234"

request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    let json = JSON(data:data!)

    debugPrint(json)
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: There is no need to ask how to write the Swift code for a Postman request, because Postman will write the Swift code for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should pass your request instead of the url to session.dataTask

here is how my code looks like:

```
private let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/")!

func httpPost(jsonData: Data) {
    if !jsonData.isEmpty {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (openTasks: [URLSessionTask]) in
            NSLog("open tasks: \(openTasks)")
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            NSLog("\(response)")
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: This code didnt work for me, but Instead I passed the request to session.dataTask. That worked.

Comment: When i pass the paramters like this It is not passed on http post request.Why? When I see on server It is as ```POST, /validate-receipt-data, {}```..... pls help me.

Comment: Please open a new question with some more details about your issue.

Answer (score 15):

I have made a Custom HTTP class where we can sent url, parameter and we will get Data from API. Below is the class.

```
import Foundation

//HTTP Methods
enum HttpMethod : String {
   case  GET
   case  POST
   case  DELETE
   case  PUT
}


class HttpClientApi: NSObject{

//TODO: remove app transport security arbitary constant from info.plist file once we get API's
 var request : URLRequest?
 var session : URLSession?

static func instance() ->  HttpClientApi{

    return HttpClientApi()
}



func makeAPICall(url: String,params: Dictionary<String, Any>?, method: HttpMethod, success:@escaping ( Data? ,HTTPURLResponse?  , NSError? ) -> Void, failure: @escaping ( Data? ,HTTPURLResponse?  , NSError? )-> Void) {

     request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    logging.print("URL = \(url)")

    if let params = params {


        let  jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

        request?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request?.httpBody = jsonData//?.base64EncodedData()


        //paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    request?.httpMethod = method.rawValue


    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    //session?.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
    //session?.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5

    session?.dataTask(with: request! as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let data = data {

            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200...299 ~= response.statusCode {
                success(data , response , error as? NSError)
            } else {
                failure(data , response as? HTTPURLResponse, error as? NSError)
            }
        }else {

            failure(data , response as? HTTPURLResponse, error as? NSError)

        }
        }.resume()

  }

}
```

Now you can refer below code to get how to make an API call.

```
  var paramsDictionary = [String:Any]()

    paramsDictionary["username"] = "BBB"
    paramsDictionary["password"]    = "refef"

    HttpClientApi.instance().makeAPICall(url: "Your URL", params:paramsDictionary, method: .POST, success: { (data, response, error) in

        // API call is Successfull

    }, failure: { (data, response, error) in

        // API call Failure

    })
```

Comment: This is simple and easy. Thank you @Balaji Galave

Comment: How can I set header and  pass something in body in  post method ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Example of POST API for calling Login API with parameters "emailaddress" and "password" with userEmailID and Userpassword as two strings holding values for email and password respectively.

You can call this POST API anywhere in your view controller, as given below:

**self.postLoginCall(url: "Your post method url")** example:                self.postLoginCall(url: "http://1.0.0.1/api/login.php")

```
func postLoginCall(url : String){


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "emailaddress=\(userEmailID!)&password=\(Userpassword!)"
    print(postString)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
        if let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:AnyObject]{
            print(responseJSON)
            print(responseJSON["status"]!)


            self.response1 = responseJSON["status"]! as! Int

            print(self.response1)

            //Check response from the sever
            if self.response1 == 200
            {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

                    //API call Successful and can perform other operatios
                   print("Login Successful")
                }

            }

            else
            {
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

                    //API call failed and perform other operations
                    print("Login Failed")

                }

            }


        }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }



    }


    task.resume()



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I share below an example of a function to make a request in POST with SWIFT 5+.

This function allows you to send a POST request with an API entry point and parameters in the form of [[String: String]] and an Int to determine the output action.

For the output actions we call a function with Switch Case.

The operation is extremely simple. You have to put the two functions in one of your classes.

```
func MGSetRequestApi(endpoint: String, parameters: [[String: String]], MGSetAction: Int) -> String {

    var setReturn: String!
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
    var MGGetParam: String! = ""

    for gate in parameters {

        for (key, value) in gate {
            let myParam = key + "=" + value + "&"
            MGGetParam.append(contentsOf: myParam)
        }
    }
            
    let postData =  MGGetParam.data(using: .utf8)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: endpoint)!,timeoutInterval: 10000)
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                    print(String(describing: error))
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            setReturn = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.MGRequestAction(MGGetIdRq: MGSetAction, MGGetData: setReturn)
        }
        semaphore.signal()

    }

    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()
    return setReturn
}
```

Then implement this function to manage the outputs

```
func MGRequestAction(MGGetIdRq: Int, MGGetData: String) {
    
    switch MGGetIdRq {
        case 1:
            // Do something here
        case 2:
            // Do something else here
        case 3:
            // Do something else here again
        default:
            print("Set default action");
    }
    
}
```

How to use this, you have two possibilities, the first one is to process what the function

> MGSetRequestApi(endpoint: String, parameters: [[String: String]], MGSetAction: Int) -> String

returns (String) or to pass by the function

> MGRequestAction(MGGetIdRq: Int, MGGetData: String)

which will call your Json parse function.

The MGRequestAction() function takes for parameter an Int for the choice of the action and the String of the return of the request

Now to use it do like this:

```
_ =  MGSetRequestApi(endpoint: MY_END_POINT_API,
                     parameters: [["KEY_1": "VALUE 1"],
                                 ["KEY_2": "VALUE 2"],
                                 ["KEY_3": "VALUE 3"],
                                 ["KEY_4": "VALUE 4"]],
                     MGSetAction: 3)
```