# How to send string key and json value in POST request parameter in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want  to send a request parameter in POST where it is Key is on String format and value is in json format as below:

```
request parameter :     data={"firstName":"Pooja"}
```

Please find below code snippet in swift 4.1

```
 let myUrl = URL(string: chatService)
        print(myUrl)
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Set POST method
        request.addValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        let postString = 'data={"firstName":"Pooja"}'
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST request through Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907542/how-to-send-a-post-request-through-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to put JSON content in query parameters. It will cause problems. If you need to include JSON in a POST, it should be in the body, not in the URL.

What you are trying to do will not work properly for a number of reasons. There are various characters that are legal in JSON but not legal in query parameters, and the length of your query parameter is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.thisismylink.com/postName.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
    print("error=\(error)")
    return
}

if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
    print("response = \(response)")
}

let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
print("responseString = \(responseString)")}task.resume()}
```

Use above code